# clang-format change one formating option in one file only

Tags: c++, customization, clang-format

We have a custom `.clang-format` file in the root folder of our repository and use clang-format with `-style=file` for all `C` and C++ files.

I like to change the formatting rules of clang-format for one file only. 
In particular I like to switch `BinPackArguments` form `true` to `false`.

I know, that I could place a `.clang-format` file in the corresponding folder. This option does effect all files in this folder.

Formatting it differently once is not an option, because our version control system will reject not formatted files.

I know, that I could turn off the formatter via the comment

```
// clang-format off
```

This has the drawback that the file is not formatted at all.

Is there a way to change one option for one file only (perhaps via a comment)?

Comment: Have you tried the `ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking` feature? Don't know if it fixes whatever you're trying to do, but might be worth a shot.

Comment: You could format all files using the standard config and then just the one file with a custom config.  What you are attempting is unusual.

Comment: FWIW I have a similar desire. We have a file full of declarations of constant string and we'd like to be able to align all of the assignment parts, even across empty lines and comments, however we don't really want to make that a general setting and, as @schorsch312 says, turning clang-format off across this file means that other aspects of formatting would be ignored. Something like the push/adjust/pop sequence you can apply to, e.g. gcc warning settings would be nice. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html